# App Engine - BlobStore- how to reference a blob by key?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, blobstore

I am writing a servlet which will get a blob out of blobstore by referencing the blobkey. I looked online but didn't find any good examples. The google site has following example:

```
BlobKey key = new BlobKey(blobkey);
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
blobstoreService.serve(key, resp);
```

So the client knows the blobkey and it sends it to the servlet. The servlet should use the key to get the blob out of blobstore and send it back in a response.

Any suggestions? In java please.

Thanks
Sarah

Comment: The above example is doing exactly that - serving the contents of blob. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read the contents of the blob into your app and do something with it, you should check out [BlobstoreInputStream](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream). The code would look something like:

```
BlobKey key = new BlobKey(blobkey);
InputStream is = new BlobInputStream(key);
```

You can now read the contents of the blob using any of the `read()` methods of `InputStream`.

Comment: The OP explicitly said they want to send the data back in a response; `BlobstoreInputStream` is the wrong solution for that.